# php calling an anonymous function

Tags: php, lambda

I have an anonymous function:

```
$rules = array(
    'asdf' => array('required'),
    'zxcv' => array('function ($data) {
    return strtoupper($data); }'),
);
```

found in the the 'zxcv' key of the $rules array. I need to call this function and I've already tried a few things including:

```
$rules['zxcv']('mydata');
```

and

```
array_map($rules['zxcv'], 'mydata');
```

and

call_user_func($rules['zxcv'], 'mydata'); to no avail

any help would be appreciated

Comment: the reason why you're not able to call it is simply because it's not actually a function. What you have there is a string. Not a function.

Comment: That's a string, not an anonymous function.

Comment: well how do I use it then?

Comment: i didn't know there was a difference

Comment: You can either eval() it (not recommended) or make it a normal function (drop the quotes).

Answer (score 4):

That's a string, not a function. Lose the quotes and make it like so:

```
$rules = array(
   'asdf' => array('required'),
   'zxcv' => function($data) { return strtoupper($data); }
);
```

Usage with [`array_map()`](http://php.net/array_map):

```
array_map($rules['zxcv'], $someArray);
```

Calling the function individually:

```
echo $rules['zxcv']('foo'); // FOO
```

[**Demo**](https://eval.in/127296)

Comment: is it really that simple?

Comment: @user3207727 Try it and see ;)

Comment: yes, it is that simple. You made it a string... and a string is not evaluated to actual PHP code.

Comment: @user3207727: Yes, really. It's that simple :)

Comment: it's working, I'm using $rules['zxcv']('foo') and its fine, thanks again, but one thing, who should I upvote? I'm not real familiar with how this forum thing works

Comment: @user3207727: It's okay. You can upvote all the helpful answers. And mark one answer as [accepted](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235/220538) so future visitors can find the solution easily.

Answer (score 3):

What you have there is a `string`, not a `function`.

What you're looking for is:

```
$rules = array(
   'asdf' => array('required'),
   'zxcv' => function($data) { return strtoupper($data);}
);
```

and you can then call it like this:

```
$rules['zxcv'](YOUR_DATA);
array_map($rules['zxcv'], YOUR_DATA);
```